# AD group added to SQL as sysadmin not allowing users to login who are part of the group

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

So I am helping with some work and we have built a few servers in Azure with their SQL server image. Everything seems healthy apart from when adding an AD group for the domain admins to access SQL i get the following error below. I can add the users in individually however thats not very practical.

AD group is Universal and a security group however i did also try creating a global group but that did not work either.

Server is configures with SQL and Windows Auth and SQL is 15.0.4188.2

> ===================================
>
> Cannot connect to W-P-SQL-VM-04.
>
> ===================================
>
> Login failed for user '****\RS_Admin'. (.Net SqlClient Data
> Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error
>
> ------------------------------ Server Name: W-P-SQL-VM-04 Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1 Line Number: 65536
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
> DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
> sqlAuthProviderManager)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
> ci, IServerType server)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Comment: You'll want to look at the state from the SQL Errorlog and not this error. Most likely it's a permissions issue as group logins have permissions applied from all relevant groups.

Comment: Use the user also a member of a group with a deny permission?

Answer (score 0):

A very basic thing but when you say "AD", do you mean Azure AD (AAD) or on-prem AD? Azure SQL Database supports [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview#authentication), so if your group isn't available in AAD (e.g. it hasn't been synchronised from on-prem AD), that could be your problem.